# Pipeline execution returns "UnresolvedUnionException: Not in union ["string","null"]" error. What is the cause?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-data-fusion

I'm developing a pipeline that reads a file from Cloud Sorage, makes some transformation in Wrangle and writes the resulting rows into a BigQuery table.

The execution returns this error:

```
org.apache.avro.file.DataFileWriter$AppendWriteException: org.apache.avro.UnresolvedUnionException: Not in union ["string","null"]: false
at org.apache.avro.file.DataFileWriter.append(DataFileWriter.java:308) ~[org.apache.avro.avro-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
at io.cdap.plugin.gcp.bigquery.sink.AvroRecordWriter.write(AvroRecordWriter.java:90) ~[%20artifact7616726366619772164.jar:na]
at io.cdap.plugin.gcp.bigquery.sink.AvroRecordWriter.write(AvroRecordWriter.java:37) ~[%20artifact7616726366619772164.jar:na]
at io.cdap.plugin.gcp.bigquery.sink.BigQueryRecordWriter.write(BigQueryRecordWriter.java:58) ~[%20artifact7616726366619772164.jar:na]
at io.cdap.plugin.gcp.bigquery.sink.BigQueryRecordWriter.write(BigQueryRecordWriter.java:32) ~[%20artifact7616726366619772164.jar:na]
at io.cdap.cdap.etl.spark.io.TrackingRecordWriter.write(TrackingRecordWriter.java:41) ~[hydrator-spark-core3_2.12-6.7.1.jar:na]
at org.apache.spark.internal.io.HadoopMapReduceWriteConfigUtil.write(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:367) ~[spark-core_2.12-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]
at org.apache.spark.internal.io.SparkHadoopWriter$.$anonfun$executeTask$1(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:137) [spark-core_2.12-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]
at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinallyAndFailureCallbacks(Utils.scala:1473) ~[spark-core_2.12-3.1.3.jar:na]
at org.apache.spark.internal.io.SparkHadoopWriter$.executeTask(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:134) [spark-core_2.12-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]
at org.apache.spark.internal.io.SparkHadoopWriter$.$anonfun$write$1(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:88) [spark-core_2.12-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90) ~[spark-core_2.12-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:131) ~[spark-core_2.12-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:498) ~[spark-core_2.12-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]
at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1439) ~[spark-core_2.12-3.1.3.jar:na]
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:501) ~[spark-core_2.12-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) ~[na:1.8.0_332]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) ~[na:1.8.0_332]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750) ~[na:1.8.0_332]
```

What could be the cause? Could it be a problem in the schema definition?
I can't see any specific field mentioned in the log. The schema is defined in JSON like (just a small fragment as sample):

```
    "schema": "{
    "type":"record",
    "name":"etlSchemaBody",
    "fields":[
        {
            "name":"Id",
            "type":["string","null"]
        },
        {
            "name":"IsDeleted",
            "type":["boolean","null"]},
...
```

Thanks and regards

Edit:
No error is returned by the execution of the flow preview.

I also tried replacing the final "BigQuery" node with another sink GCS node to a JSON file, and it works fine, so I guess the problem is in the BigQuery sink node

Comment: Does the BigQuery table already exist? If yes, does the schema of the existing table match the output schema of your sink plugin?

Comment: @user3126412
I finally found the problem.
As you said, there were a couple of fields that in the BigQuery table were of type String, while in my pipeline schema they were of type bool or timestamp.That's why the error occurred when writing in BigQuery.
Thank you very much